# My app permissions

Tags: ios, permissions, restrictions

I want to make the app for IOS that can reed the info about the time i spent in others applications. **Read only**. Is there any way to get that stat info? *Thank U for your time!*

Comment: Thank god there is no way to do that. This would be a huge privacy breach !

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to get this info and apple wouldn't allow such app to take info about other apps.